# How to get data from related tables like in django rest framework browsable API

Tags: django, angularjs, django-rest-framework

I need to populate a form through Angularjs which should get the data from an API. The API should return data from user table and also data from static tables (plan, country) which are related to the user table through foreign key.

Serializers:

```
class CountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Country
       queryset = Country.objects.all()
       fields = ('id','name')   

class PlanSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Plan
       queryset = Plan.objects.all()
       fields = ('id','details')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    plan = PlanSerializer()
    conutry = CountrySerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name','plan','role','country',)
```

My User model:

```
class User(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
   role = models.ForeignKey(User_Role, null = True, blank = True)
   plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan, null = True, blank = True)
   country = models.ForeignKey(Country, null = True, blank = True)
```

I will make a call to the `UserSerializer` API from Angularjs, which should return the user's name, plan, role, country and also list of other plans, country from the corresponding table.

Basically I need to update the plan, country for the user, and so I need to have other plan/country details from plan/country table so that I can send PUT/PATCH request to update it. it is very similar to the Django rest framework browsable API HTML form (for PUT) except I use Angularjs to get the data from server.

All I want is an API which picks data for the corresponding user which also gets additional data from other static tables(plan,country tables) which are helpful to update certain fields(like plan,country).

Comment: Can you describe more precisely what the problem is? i.e. what exactly are you getting from the API vs what you expect.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Iam having an API which at the time of loading the page will get details for User(say user1) like his name,plan,country etc. The plan and country are foreign key to user table from Plan and Country table. I want the api to return the row corresponding to user1 and also it should also pick all the data from Plan and Country table and send them along.

Comment: What am getting now is json {'name':'xxx','plan':{'id':1,'desc':'test1'}, 'country':{'id':1,'name':'USA'}} what i need is {'name':'xxx','plan':{'id':1,'desc':'test1'}, 'country':{'id':1,'name':'USA'}} + {'plan':[{'id':1,'desc':'test1'},{'id':2,'desc':'test2'},{'id':3,'desc':'test4'}],'country':[{'id':1,'name':'USA'},{'id':2,'name':'UK'},{'id':3,'name':'FRANCE'}]}

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to achieve here (returning different types of objets in the same response) is not very compliant with the idea of REST, so it's unlikely that the "django-rest-framework" would let you do that.

You probably should make 3 API Calls here:

- 1 to get the user
- 1 to get the list of countries
- 1 to get the list of plans

Comment: Thanks Thomas, Is it advisable to get n-api calls for just loading a single form? I am having 10 static tables and all these data are needed for the single form.Do you advise me to write 10+1 api calls to get all the static data and user related data from server. P.S I make all API calls through angularJS

Comment: @mithu Doing it this way is the simpler way; start with this, benchmark performance, and optimize one you've established whether this is a bottleneck. Bear in mind that JavaScript will make the requests in parallel (though, surely there will be a bit of overhead because multiple connections must be established, and because you can't have an unlimited number of requests to a single server). Consider using caching to make those requests less often.

Comment: Thanks will do it that way.

Comment: It should be achieved in one api calls.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, get n-api calls it is not the best idea.
You can use [Django REST framework nested serialization](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization)

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name','plan','role','country',)
        depth = 1
```